# How to start a new line of an array of squares with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a 'grid' of squares using CSS. So far I've tried:

```css
.square {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

However, this simply display 6 squares in a row. I'd like to have two rows of 3 squares each, however. Why do the encompassing `div`s not have the 'normal' behavior that they are displayed beneath each other?

Comment: Try to write your question in the jsfiddle plugin provided.

Comment: Respectfully, there is no array of squares in your example. It's several `div` elements. See CSS's new Grid, or, CSS Flexbox depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to clear your floatting elements

> https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/
>
> **Clearing the Float**
>
> Float's sister property is clear. An element that has the clear property set on it will not move up adjacent to the float like the float desires, but will move itself down past the float....

```css
.square {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 30px;
}
body>div {overflow:hidden;}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because of `float: left`.

**Option 1:**

Use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`:

```css
.square {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Option 2**
Use clearfix in parent div:

```css
.square {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 30px;
}
.parent{
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class="parent">
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.square-wrapper {
width: 276px;
}
.square {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 30px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="square-wrapper">
<div class="square">1</div>
<div class="square">2</div>
<div class="square">3</div>
</div>

<div class="square-wrapper">
<div class="square">4</div>
<div class="square">5</div>
<div class="square">6</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the blocks inside of a containing div that has a fixed width. This will force the blocks to stack given their display type. For example, placing the width of the container to 400px makes enough space for only three blocks in a row. Frameworks use a system that is very useful for creating grids that are evenly dispersed throughout the container.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.square {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 30px;
  }
.container {
    width:400px;   
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Place all of your blocks in a single container -->

<div class="container">

<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<!-- The container is not large enough to display all of the blocks in one row -->
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```